# How do I implement autocomplete table view google maps swift?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I am trying to implement google maps autocomplete for cities. When they type in the text field, the table view should auto populate with potential cities based on the user's input. For now, I want to print the results in the log, but I am not sure if I am doing this correctly. This is the kind of results that appears in my log `Result Austin{
    GMSAutocompleteMatch = "<GMSAutocompleteMatchFragment: 0x608000235e60>";
}`

```
var placesClient: GMSPlacesClient!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    placesClient = GMSPlacesClient.shared()

}



func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        placeAutoComplete()
        return true
    }

    func placeAutoComplete() {
        let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
        filter.type = .city
        placesClient.autocompleteQuery(cityField.text!, bounds: nil, filter: filter, callback: {(results, error) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                print("Autocomplete error \(error)")
                return
            }
            if let results = results {
                for result in results {
                    print("Result \(result.attributedPrimaryText)")
                }
            }
        })

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing an attributed string. This should not appear when you display it in a `UILable`'s`attributedText` property. See my example below

when you call for `result in results` save results in an array and reload the tableview by calling `tableView.reloadData`. In your tableView data source set the number of rows to the number of items in your array. Then inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` do the following

```
let result = resultArray[indexPath.row] as? GMSAutocompletePrediction
cell.textLabel.attributedText = result.attributedPrimaryText
```

Comment: Not really trying to replace the string, instead I need the potential results in an array so I can post it inside my table view. For example, when I type 'A' I should see Austin, other cities starting with A

Comment: as long as your set your text field delegate to the class you have shown above, everytime you enter text into the text field you will fire off the method `shouldChangeCharachtersInRange`. At that point you will call `placeAutoComplete()`. Then inside `placeAutoComplete()` method store all of your results into an array. Then, reload the tableView by `tableView.reloadData()` and inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` set the `cell.textLabel.attributedText = resultArray[index.row].attributedPrimaryText`